# Taking the homology of a chain complex, seen as a symmetric monoidal functor

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I've found, in quite some places online (e.g. it's the last example in the wikipedia page about [monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor#Examples)), a statement similar to this:

> Homology can be seen as a symmetric, monoidal functor $\mathbf{Ch}(\mathbf{Ab}) \to \mathbf{Ab}^{Gr}$ from the category of chain complexes of abelian groups (with the usual symmetric monoidal structure), with values in the category of graded abelian groups (again, with the usual symmetric monoidal structure).

I think I can see why this should be the case, but I'd like a paper/book spelling this out (more or less) explicitly. I've been looking for such a reference for a couple of days, without success: can anyone help?

Comment: A lax one, BTW.

Comment: This makes sense to me: it's coherent with the terminology used in the wikipedia page, and kind of "explains" where the Tor functor comes from in (the algebraic version of) Kunneth's formula. Also, I think I've figured out a reference: appendix 3B in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, specifically the part before theorem 3B.5. Does it check out to you?